# Select on subquery not working

Tags: oracle, subquery

I having problems to use a sub-query as a table in Oracle 11g
The query below is just a simplified version of the real one to exhibit the problem.

I have a hierarchical query on a view that returns some rows:

```
select parent_entity_id, child_entity_id
from V_COMPLEX_VIEW
  start with parent_entity_id is null
  connect by parent_entity_id = prior child_entity_id
```

If I use the same query as a sub-query without "where", I expect to get same result, but I receive no data:

```
select tab1.*
from ( select parent_entity_id, child_entity_id
       from V_COMPLEX_VIEW
         start with parent_entity_id is null
         connect by parent_entity_id = prior child_entity_id ) tab1
```

If I exchange the view *V_COMPLEX_VIEW* by a table with same content, both queries give same results.

I know the use of sub-query in the example seem to be unnecessary, but it is just to explain the problem.

Any ideas about this?

Comment: weird! Are you sure you running both the queries in the same schema?

Comment: Same schema and same session.